# Preciso saber realizar herança em meu programa python

Tags: python

```
from random import randint


class PersonagemP:
    def __init__(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome
        self.posicao = str('DEF')
        self.pontosATK = int(randint(5, 20))
        self.pontosDEF = int(randint(5, 20))
        self.pontosRFL = int(randint(5, 20))
        self.pontosLife = int(50)
        self.barraEspecial = int(3)


class Invocador(PersonagemP):
    def __init__(self, nome):
        super().__init__(nome, pontosATK, pontosDEF, pontosRFL, pontosLife, barraEspecial)
        self.nome = nome
        self.pontos_ATK = pontosATK - 3
        self.pontos_DEF = pontosDEF - 3
        self.pontos_RFL = pontosRFL - 3
        self.pontos_Life = pontosLife + 5
        self.barra_Especial = barraEspecial + 3


Main1 = Invocador('Pedro')
print(Main1)
print(Main1.nome)
print(Main1.pontosATK)
```

No caso eu estou fazendo uma classe para um jogo RPG, porém eu preciso utilizar uma outra classe para fazer um outro tipo de personagem, no caso a primeira é para fazer o personagem base e a segunda que é a herdeira está formando um novo tipo de personagem, porém não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Só uma dica, `randint` retorna um inteiro então não tem necessidade de converter usando `int`. O mesmo vale para `str("DEF")`, `int(50)` e os outros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pode ver, na sua classe `Pai`, você tem apenas um atributo no construtor, o atributo `nome`, então a sua chamada na classe `Filho` deve passar apenas esse atributo.

```
class Invocador(PersonagemP):
    def __init__(self, nome):
        super().__init__(nome)
        ...
```

Agora como você precisa buscar os valores que foram definidos na sua classe `Pai` (os valores aleatórios gerados), você precisa apenas utilizar o `self` para se referir à eles.

```
class Invocador(PersonagemP):
    def __init__(self, nome):
        super().__init__(nome)
        self.nome = nome
        self.pontos_ATK = self.pontosATK - 3
        self.pontos_DEF = self.pontosDEF - 3
        self.pontos_RFL = self.pontosRFL - 3
        self.pontos_Life = self.pontosLife + 5
        self.barra_Especial = self.barraEspecial + 3
```

E como teste iremos obter algo semelhante à

```
Main1 = Invocador('Pedro')
print(Main1)
print(Main1.nome)
print(Main1.pontosATK)

>> <__main__.Invocador object at 0x000002A033D5AB20>
>> Pedro
>> 15
```

Comment: Uma dica seria alterar os nomes das variáveis na classe `PersonagemP`, para algo como `generatedATK`, para não haver confusão na hora de saber qual que é o ataque do seu `Invocador`, que no seu caso é `pontos_ATK` e não `pontosATK`.